# How to carry out custom initialisation with autofac

Tags: inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm adding autofac to an existing project and some of the service implementations require their Initialize method to be called and passed configuration information. Currently I'm using the code:

```
builder.Register(context =>
                 {
                    var service = 
                         new SqlTaxRateProvider(context.Resolve<IUserProvider>());
                    service.Initialize(config);
                    return service;
                 }
).As<ITaxService>()
.SingleInstance();
```

which works but I'm still creating the object myself which is what I'm trying to get away from this and allow autofac to handle it for me. Is it possible to configure a post create operation that would carry out the custom initialisation?

To give you an idea of what I'm after ideally this would be the code:

```
builder.RegisterType<SqlTaxRateProvider>()
 .As<ITaxService>()
 .OnCreated(service=> service.Initialize(config))
 .SingleInstance();
```

Update:
I am using Autofac-2.1.10.754-NET35

Comment: A better option would be to move away from having an Initialize method in the first place. Use **Constructor Injection** instead.

Comment: I agree, at some stage I’ll get around it, I was just looking for a quick solution to make my initial changes easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.OnActivating(e => e.Instance.Initialize(...))
```

should do the trick.

You might also investigate the Startable module (see the [Startable entry in the Autofac wiki](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html)).

Mark's suggestion to do initialisation in the constructor is also a good one. In that case use

```
.WithParameter(new NamedParameter("config", config))
```

to merge the config parameter in with the other constructor dependencies.

Comment: Startable module? I feel like I heard the name somewhere... or similar

Comment: Thanks Nick, I think the NamedParameter will help eliminate the Initialize() method

Comment: @Krzysztof yep, Apache Avalon lives on :)