# Autofac: Call initialise method when registering component

Tags: c#, autofac

I was just wondering if it's possible to call a method in my service, when I register it.

```
public interface IDataService
{
   User GetUserById(int id);
   void SaveUser(int id, User user);
}

public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public User GetUserById(int id) 
    { 
       // do stuff 
    };

    public void SaveUser(int id, User user) 
    { 
       // do stuff 
    };

    public void InitialiseService() { };
}
```

When I register this component is it possible to call InitialiseService so my service is initialised?

```
builder.RegisterType<DataService>()
                    .Keyed<IDataService>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
                    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                    .SingleInstance();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320536/how-to-carry-out-custom-initialisation-with-autofac

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `OnActivating` pseudo event :

```
builder.RegisterType<DataService>()
       .Keyed<IDataService>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .OnActivating(e => e.Instance.InitialiseService())
       .SingleInstance();
```

it looks like you are doing a singleton so you may also consider implement the [`IStartable`](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html#startable-components) interface which will automatically be instanciated by *Autofac*

```
public class DataService : IDataService, IStartable
{
    public User GetUserById(int id) 
    { 
       // do stuff 
    }

    public void SaveUser(int id, User user) 
    { 
       // do stuff 
    }

    public void Start() 
    {

    }
}
```

or use the [`AutoActivate`](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html#auto-activated-components) method to let *Autofac* create the instance automatically.

```
builder.RegisterType<DataService>()
       .Keyed<IDataService>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .AutoActivate()
       .SingleInstance();
```

or use the [`RegisterBuildCallback`](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html#container-build-callbacks) method on a `ContainerBuilder` to do things after the container has been built

```
builder.RegisterType<DataService>()
       .Keyed<IDataService>(FiberModule.Key_DoNotSerialize)
       .AsImplementedInterfaces()
       .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterBuildCallback(c => c.Resolve<IDataSerialize>().Initialise());
```

Comment: Container build callbacks is a third option. http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/startup.html#container-build-callbacks